# Adding .so library. unexpected e_machine: 62 error

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-emulator

I am trying to add a .so file to my android studio project, but get an error when trying to load it in a java file. I have added the .so library to jniLibs/arm64-v8a, jniLibs/armeabi-v7a, jniLibs/x86, and jniLibs/x86_64 with the name libopendnp3java.so. And I have added the following to the defautConfig of my build.gradle.

```
 ndk {
      abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
 }
```

I added the following to my gradle.properties file

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

And I am calling the library in my ReportActivity.java with

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opendnp3java");
}
```

When I run the program on my Galaxy S7 (Android Version 7.0) in developer mode, I get the following error

```
05-28 11:15:23.835 1509-1509/com.company.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.example, PID: 1509
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.comapny.example-1/lib/arm64/libopendnp3java.so" has unexpected e_machine: 62
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
    at com.company.example.ReportActivity.<clinit>(ReportActivity.java:49)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2834)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I have looked on StackOverflow and other websites for the error `unexpected e_machine: 62` but could not find anything. The closest was `unexpected e_machine: 40` but the solutions for those issues did not work for me

EDIT: I tried using the following in my build.gradle as a replacement for ndk but it does not change anything

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Am I missing another step or did I add the file to the wrong directory?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 2: I tried running it on a Pixel 2 XL API P x86_64 Emulator. The libopendnp3java.so file was found and read correctly, but I received a new error

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libasiodnp3.so.2" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
```

I have this .so file in the same location as the other one so I am not sure why it has not been found.

Any ideas that you may have would be very grateful!

Comment: Did you ever fixed this?

Comment: Any update on this?